# What does "confound-its" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I've come across it in the 12th episode of the 1st season of *Scrubs*. Here is the context:

> Dr. Cox: All right, bring it in here, you knuckle-heads. Come on, take
> a knee if you need to, you **confound-its**. I have been on since midnight
> -- so I stand here with my usual level of contempt for all of you, but with the added wrinkle of having thirteen cups of Nurse Roberts'
> piss-poor excuse for coffee passing pretty much straight through me.

Comment: The character invented this term. "Confound it!" is an old-fashioned expression of exasperation. This character turns it into a noun as an insult for people who frustrate him/her. 0/10 on the "worth learning" scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Confound it" is a slightly dated expression of annoyance.  Similar but not as strong as "damn it"

> Confound it! I can't find my keys again.

The doctor's use of "confound its" as a noun is his own (or his scriptwriter's) invention.  It apparently means "people who would make you say 'confound it'", that is "annoying people".

It's not an expression to learn and use.